# How do I accept info from a file and input it into an array?

Tags: c

I have a file with these values:

```
9 10 11 9.5 10.2 9.8 10 8.7 9.3 9.1 9 8.9
4 5 5 4 6 5 4 3 4 5 5 4
8 11 10 8.5 10.7 9 11 8.5 9.4 9 10 9.9
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
4 5 5 4 6 5 4 3 4 5 5 4
8 9 10 8.5 9.2 8.8 9 7.7 8.3 8.1 8 7.9
7 4 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 6 5 6 
10 11 12 10 11.2 9 11 9.7 9 9.1 10 9.9
6 5 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 6 5 6 
10 9 11.2 9.5 10.8 9 10.3 8 9.3 9.1 9 8.9
5 4 5 4 6 5 4 3 4 5 5 4
9 10 10.4 8.5 10.2 9.2 11.1 8 9.4 9 10 9.9
6 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
10 8 9.6 9 9.6 9.7 9 9 9.7 8 10 9
5 4 5 4 6 5 4 3 4 5 5 4
9 8 10.8 8.5 9.5 8 9.5 7 8.3 8.1 8.8 9
5 4 5 4 6 5 4 3 4 5 5 4
11 10 11 10 11.3 9.4 11 9 9.5 8 10 7
4 5 5 4 6 5 4 3 4 5 5 4
```

I need to accept these values into an array, so I can then get the largest number out of every other line, and the lowest out of the other lines.

Say I make an array

```
float array[20][12];
```

This doesn't seem to work:
`fscanf(ifp, "%f", &main_array[20][12]);`

So how can I accept these values into my array?

Comment: if your file is a text file, you have to go over it line by line and over every element in line and scan them into a proper array entry.

Answer (score 1):

you need to read value by value, using a loop, you could make something like this:

```
float array[20][12];
int n = 20 * 12;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    fscanf(ifp, "%f", (&array[0][0] + i));
```

That's because you cannot read all file at once.

Another way, and maybe more easy to understand(because not uses pointer arithmetic) is:

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 12; j++)
     fscanf(ifp, "%f", &array[i][j]);
```